# Getting Invalid Token error when trying to access variables in a class that will be used multiple times by Windows Forms in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am a C# beginner, and have been working through some code where I can type in the day of the week for a given month and then the dates (3/29/2019) that match the day (For example, Friday) are printed out. I have successfully got this working using a console app.

I'd like to now have the same functionality while using Forms. I've watched multiple videos and done research on implementing Forms and while it seems rather simple, I'd like to have most of the code running outside of the buttons in its own class so that I don't have to enter the same code each and every time for each button (Example shown below).

Here is my code in Forms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DesktopApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public class A
        {

            public static void Main()
            {

                DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;

                //Creates 2 strings with year and month
                string currentyearstr = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                string currentmonthstr = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

                //Turns two strings into integers for further use
                int currentyear = int.Parse(currentyearstr);
                int selectmonth = int.Parse(currentmonthstr);

                //Outputs total days for the current month, Number of times to loop command
                var totaldaysinmonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentyear, selectmonth);

                List<string> meetingdates = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < totaldaysinmonth; i++)
                {
                    DateTime dateofmonth = new DateTime(timenow.Year, timenow.Month, 1 + i);


                    Calendar mycal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
                    string dayofweek = mycal.GetDayOfWeek(dateofmonth).ToString();



                    if (dayofweek == "Friday")
                    {
                        meetingdates.Add(dateofmonth.Date.ToString("MM/dd"));

                    }







                }

    }


}




public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = A.currentyearstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result: I created the A class to keep variables that I would be using for throughout different places, such as textboxes in the same place. I am expecting to be able to locate the `currentyearstr` variable for example.

I understand that if I only create the class and do not have the code inside of `Main()` that it is then accessible after declaring string, int, and others `static`. The problem I have with this is that then `if` and `for` do not function if they are not inside the `Main()`. Atleast that's what I think anyways. What I just described, can be seen here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace DesktopApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static class A
        {

            static DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;


            //Creates 2 strings with year and month
            public static string currentyearstr = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            static string currentmonthstr = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

            //Turns two strings into integers for further use
            static int currentyear = int.Parse(currentyearstr);
            static int selectmonth = int.Parse(currentmonthstr);

            //Outputs total days for the current month, Number of times to loop command
            static var totaldaysinmonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentyear, selectmonth);


            //Gives all dates in the month

            static List<string> meetingdates = new List<string>();
            static for (int i = 0; i<totaldaysinmonth; i++)
            {
                static DateTime dateofmonth = new DateTime(timenow.Year, timenow.Month, 1 + i);


            Calendar mycal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
            static string dayofweek = mycal.GetDayOfWeek(dateofmonth).ToString();



                static if (dayofweek == "Friday")
                {
                     meetingdates.Add(dateofmonth.Date.ToString("MM/dd"));   
                }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = A.currentyearstr;
        }


    }



}
```

One doubt I have is why do I have to specify in this case that everything is static? when in the first example, when most of the code is in `Main`, I only needed to do this once. I understand that public is what allows me use the variable outside of the class.

The errors that appear are this:

```
Invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member
Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member
```

What is the cause of these errors? As a higher level question, how should I organize code that will be repeatedly used, so that it is accessible to all other classes? In my project for example, I need to call on those strings different integers, strings, and datetime, when using different windows forms.

Thanks ahead of time for any help. It is much appreciated. :)

Edit:

Per comment below here is my new code now that I have employed a method `DatesCalculated`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace DesktopApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public class A
        {
            public void DatesCalculated(string[] args)
            {

                DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;

                //Creates 2 strings with year and month
                string currentyearstr = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                string currentmonthstr = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

                //Turns two strings into integers for further use
                int currentyear = int.Parse(currentyearstr);
                int selectmonth = int.Parse(currentmonthstr);

                //Outputs total days for the current month, Number of times to loop command
                var totaldaysinmonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentyear, selectmonth);


                //Gives all dates in the month

                List<string> meetingdates = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < totaldaysinmonth; i++)
                {
                    DateTime dateofmonth = new DateTime(timenow.Year, timenow.Month, 1 + i);


                    Calendar mycal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
                    string dayofweek = mycal.GetDayOfWeek(dateofmonth).ToString();



                    if (dayofweek == "Friday")
                    {
                        meetingdates.Add(dateofmonth.Date.ToString("MM/dd"));
                    }
                }

                return;


            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop has to exist within a method. It's not possible to declare it as a class member.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class, its members can be fields, properties, and methods.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    static string _thisIsAField = "hello!";
    static string ThisIsAProperty {get; set;}
    static int ThisIsAMethod(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}
```

A `for` loop isn't any one of those things, so you can't do this:

```
static for (int i = 0; i<totaldaysinmonth; i++)
```

A `for` loop can only exist within a method. "Invalid token" means that the compiler doesn't understand what it means in the place where you're putting it. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you would have to create a method that does something, like (this is a really lame example)

```
static List<int> GetRangeOfNumbers(int start, int end)
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    for(var x = start; x <= end; x++)
    {
        list.Add(x);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, it has helped me learn and understand Methods better. I have fixed my code so that a method is now used.  I do still have one question, how do I use the variables that are in the method?

Ultimately I'd need the `meetingdates` to be available for other classes, in this case.

I updated the original post above to reflect the new changes.

Comment: Nevermind, I had forgotten to declare my variable outside of the method. Thanks again for all your help.